# Why does this shell script fail in bash, but the commands work in SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh, tar

What I'm trying to write is a shell script that will back up a website and all the MySQL DBs that support it.  I found examples all over the 'net, but when I run the script in bash in a jailed SSH session, it fails.  If I type the commands straight into the SSH session, they work fine.

```
#!/bin/sh

DB1="first_db"
THEDATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
THEUSER=user
THEDBPW=password

mysqldump -u $THEDBUSER -p$THEDBPW $DB1 > dbbackup_$DB1_$THEDATE.sql

tar -czf sitebackup_website_$THEDATE.tar /home/website/public_html
gzip sitebackup_website_$THEDATE.tar
```

This script lives on the web server, so for testing purposes, I SSH into the server, `cd` into the directory, and run `bash backup.sh`.  `mysqldump` isn't connecting, seeming to fail to pass the password in (it returns an error reporting 'using password: NO').  Then the tar command fails, reporting that it can't stat `/home/website/public_html` with a 'no such file or directory'.  `tar` then reports it is exiting with error status due to previous errors.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you explain what "a jailed SSH session" means. Are you running `ssh foo chroot /bar bash backup.sh`? Does it work without the `chroot`?

Comment: Do you still have problems if you quote your variables? Use `"$var"` or `"${var}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the script for Windows line endings by logging in on the server and running

```
cat -v /path/to/script
```

If the line ends with `^M`, that is the problem.

You can fix a file with broken line endings by running

```
dos2unix /path/to/script
```

If dos2unix doesn't exist on the server, you can instead use sed, like this:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' /path/to/script
```

Comment: This was exactly it.  Once I ran `dos2unix` on the script, it worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned the username to variable `THEUSER`, but your `mysqldump` command is using the variable `THEDBUSER`.

Comment: That's true, but why would that give an error saying it can't start at all because of 'no such file of directory'?

Comment: Nice catch - I did have the same mistake in the file.  At least I caught that, with your help, before I tried to run the script again.

Answer (score 0):

```
tardir=$PWD ; cd /home/website/public_html && 
    tar -czf "$tardir"/sitebackup_complete-office_"$THEDATE.tar"
```

or just:

```
tar -C/home/website/public_html -czf \
    sitebackup_complete-office_"$THEDATE.tar"
```

In general many `tars` will fail to work at all with absolute paths unless [explicitly instructed](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/tar-1.13/html_chapter/tar_toc.html#TOC104) to do so.

> By default, GNU tar drops a leading `/` on input or output,and complains about file names containing a `..` component. This option
>   turns off this behavior.

It's entirely possible that `ssh's` commands are resolving paths beforehand depending on command delivery and quoting. The same is relevant to the expansion of the variables in your pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you description of the problem correctly, the key difference seems to be the **jailed** SSH session - processes running inside the jailed session cannot see outside of their jail directory (often their home). That's why you don't experience problems in non-jailed session. Yo might also have a look at the [wikipedia Jail entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jail_%28computer_security%29) for more details.

Comment: It's not clear to me that "typing the command directly into the ssh session" refers to a non-jailed session - but it would be nice to have it verified.

Comment: You're right, Jenny D - all SSH is jailed for me.